# Databinding not working for user control - PropertyChanged always null

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem with data binding. A test application that I have looks as follows:

There's a mainwindow:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        x:Name="main"
        Title="MainWindow" >
    <StackPanel >
        <Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Controls:UserControl1 />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And a user control:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl1"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 x:Name="uc"
                 >
        <Grid >
            <TextBox Width="40" Text="{Binding ElementName=main, 
Path=Status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

I want to click the button on the main window to have the value of text box in user control updated:

The code of MainWindow file:

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string _status;
        public string Status
        {
            get { return _status; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _status)
                {
                    _status = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Status");
                }
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Status == "one")
                Status = "two";
            else
                Status = "one";
        }
    }
}
```

And the code of UserControl:

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
        public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, e: new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why doesn't it work, but the PropertyChanged is always null. The example is in the simplest form I can imagine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the parent window using the ElementName binding, as far as I am aware, that is not possible. You can however use a relative source binding to get the parent window:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=Status}" ... />
```

Follow up edit:

Your child user control should look like this:

```
<UserControl 
         ...
         x:Name="usr">
   <Grid>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message, ElementName=usr}"/>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You will then need to create a dependency property called 'Message' (This is just an example, I'm not sure what you want to call this property).

```
public partial class YourUserControl: UserControl
{
    public string Message
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MessageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MessageProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Message.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Message", typeof(string), typeof(YourUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then, when you declare this in your parent user control, simply set the binding of the Message property to whatever property you need to bind to in your parent user control:

```
<YourNamespace:YourUserControl Message="{Binding PropertyName, ElementName=elementName}" />
```

Comment: thanks - that helps in the test app - in my actual project I am referencing a user control - I tried with AncestorType=UserControl, but it doesn't help. What should I do there?

Comment: No problem, are you saying that you have a user control within a user control? And you need to reference the parent?

Comment: Yes @Mike, basically to have the layout neat, I have a window, which contains a large usercontrol (sort of tabpage). This tabpage contains a webbrowser and a user control - statusstrip. On navigating event of browser, I want to display a message on the statusStrip.

So, MainWindow contains a parent user control which contains a child user control. I want to update a text box on child user control with a method defined on parent user control.

Comment: Ok, in this scenario, you will need a different method. The solution is to create a dependency property on your child user control, then when you declare the user control in the parent user control, simply bind the dependency property to the property on your parent user control using an ElementName binding. Phew, did that even make sense? Would you like me to provide an example?

Comment: hm, yeah, if you could do that I'd be very grateful!

Comment: That should do it, let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: thanks a lot. That is a pretty diffucult stuff, very unintuitive to me. Hopefully, with time, I'll feel better with it, but for now, I hate it.

Have a great weekend (thanks again!)

Comment: There's a lot to it, but once you pick it up everything will make sense and you will appreciate it more :-) In the meantime I would advise looking up some MVVM tutorials. Topics like DependencyProperties are a bit of a pain to get your head around. Good luck!